# How to update user/group settings of a running process?

Tags: process, users, group, privileges

Suppose I change some user settings like its initial login group or add it to a new group. I now can do `su user` and work with these new settings. But all the previously running processes will still have the same permissions as before.

How can I force a specific running process to re-read `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` to reinitialize its user and group settings, without terminating any activity it was doing? I've tried attaching to the process with `gdb` and do `print setuid(MY_USER_ID)`, but despite the result was `0` (i.e. success), the process still remained with the same data (checked on `bash` running `groups` to see whether additional group has appeared).

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting attempt.  Actually, process's supplementary groups (defined in `/etc/group`) are set by [`setgroups`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setgroups.2.html) system call.  It requires `CAP_SETGID` privilege or being root.

So you can do like this:

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

# gdb -q id
Reading symbols from id...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) b getgroups
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401990
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/id 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, getgroups () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) call setgroups(5, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
$1 = 0
(gdb) d 1
(gdb) c
Continuing.
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(daemon),2(bin),3(sys),4(adm),5(tty)
[Inferior 1 (process 8059) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: But this wouldn't work for a non-root process, right? Does a process have to become root first to reinit its groups?

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, therefore you need to start another session for group changes to take effect, and `/usr/bin/newgrp` is a setuid command.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a rather pointless exercise.

Target process not only may not have all rights necessary to switch credentials, it may have its uid/gid stored somewhere and actively used, so a surprise credential change may actually break things.

There are various entities which know who owns them - files, sysv ipc.

So you would need to /stop/ all target processes and updated all possible places.

But some processes may be blocked in an uninterruptible manner in the kernel - now what?

For toy purposes, you would need a kernel module changing credentials for processes, but even that cannot easily deal with blocked processes.

Or in other words: what are you really trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: Actually what I want to accomplish doesn't depend on what the process does with its uid/gid etc. I'm just trying to grant/deny it some permission from now on, but not having to stop the process, which may be in the middle of something (not in disk sleep anyway) or whatever.

Comment: In that case you want to investigate LSM modules instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I also encounter this issue frequently. This is a Linux kernel defect (which can pose some data security concerns), thus, no user-level programs can do it. So I have explicitly made a kernel-module program for doing this.

```
#include <linux/cred.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/pid.h>
#include <linux/pid_namespace.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/uidgid.h>


static int arg_pid=0;
static int arg_gid=0;
static char *arg_act="add";

module_param(arg_pid, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(arg_pid, "PID of the process");
module_param(arg_gid, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(arg_gid, "GID of the group to add to PID's supplimentary groups");
module_param(arg_act, charp, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(arg_act, "action to perform: add/remove/list/query");

struct pid *pid_struct = NULL;
struct task_struct *task = NULL;
struct cred *real_cd = NULL;
struct cred *effe_cd = NULL;
struct group_info *gi = NULL;
struct group_info *new_gi = NULL;

bool query(int gid, struct group_info *gi){
    for(int x=0; x<gi->ngroups; ++x)
        if(gid==gi->gid[x].val) return true;
    return false;
}

int init_module(void) {
    if(arg_pid==0){
        pr_info("Error: Usage: insmod supgroup.ko arg_pid=## arg_gid=## (arg_act='add/remove/list/query') && rmmod supgroup\n");
        return 0;
    }
    pid_struct = find_get_pid(arg_pid);
    if(pid_struct==NULL){
        pr_info("Error: find_get_pid() failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    task = pid_task(pid_struct, PIDTYPE_PID);
    if(task==NULL){
        pr_info("Error: pid_task() failed\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(task->real_cred==NULL){
        pr_info("Error: task->real_cred == NULL\n");
        return 0;
    }
    gi = task->real_cred->group_info;
    if(gi==NULL){
        pr_info("Error: task->real_cred->group_info == NULL\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(!strcmp(arg_act, "add")){
        if(query(arg_gid, gi)){
            pr_info("GID %d is already in PID %d's supplementary group list\n", arg_gid, arg_pid);
            return 0;
        }
        new_gi = groups_alloc(gi->ngroups+1);
        if(new_gi==NULL){
            pr_info("Error: groups_alloc() failed, out of kernel memory?\n");
            return 0;
        }
        for(int x=0; x<gi->ngroups; ++x)
            new_gi->gid[x] = gi->gid[x];
        new_gi->gid[gi->ngroups].val = arg_gid;
        groups_sort(new_gi);

        // forcefully set group_info
        get_cred((const struct cred *)new_gi);
        *(struct group_info**)(&task->real_cred->group_info) = new_gi;
        *(struct group_info**)(&task->cred->group_info) = new_gi;

        pr_info("Added GID %d to PID %d's supplementary groups\n", arg_gid, arg_pid);
    }else if(!strcmp(arg_act, "remove")){
        if(!query(arg_gid, gi)){
            pr_info("GID %d is not in PID %d's supplementary group list\n", arg_gid, arg_pid);
            return 0;
        }
        new_gi = groups_alloc(gi->ngroups-1);
        if(new_gi==NULL){
            pr_info("Error: groups_alloc() failed, out of kernel memory?\n");
            return 0;
        }
        for(int x=0,y=0; x<gi->ngroups; ++x)
            if(gi->gid[x].val != arg_gid){
                new_gi->gid[y] = gi->gid[x];
                y++;
            }

        // forcefully set group_info
        get_cred((const struct cred *)new_gi);
        *(struct group_info**)(&task->real_cred->group_info) = new_gi;
        *(struct group_info**)(&task->cred->group_info) = new_gi;

        pr_info("Removed GID %d from PID %d's supplementary groups\n", arg_gid, arg_pid);
    }else if(!strcmp(arg_act, "list")){
        pr_info("Listing PID %d's supplementary groups' GIDs: ", arg_pid);
        for(int x=0; x<gi->ngroups; ++x)
            pr_info("%d ", gi->gid[x].val);
        pr_info("Done\n");
    }else if(!strcmp(arg_act, "query")){
        pr_info("GID %d is %s PID %d's supplementary group list\n", arg_gid, query(arg_gid, gi)?"in":"not in", arg_pid);
    }

    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Checkout the detailed usage at my Github repo (https://github.com/xuancong84/supgroup).
This is useful for Linux system administrators.